# How to find next N elements from a cursor with MongoDB, without _id and on a sorted cursor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, mongodb-query

Let's say I have three person documents in a MongoDB, inserted in a random order.

```
{
  "firstName": "Hulda",
  "lastName": "Lamb",
},
{
  "firstName": "Austin",
  "lastName": "Todd",
},
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
}
```

My goal is to obtain, let's say, the next person after Austin when the list is in alphabetical order. So I would like to get the person with firstName = Hulda.
We can assume that I know Austin's `_id`.
My first attempt was to rely on the fact that `_id` is incremental, but it won't work because the persons can be added in any order in the database. Hulda's `_id` field has a value less than Austin's. I cannot do something like `{_id: {$gt: <Austin's _id here>}};`
And I also need to limit the number of returned elements, so N is a dynamic value.

Here is the code I have now, but as I mentioned, the ID trick is not working.

```
let cursor: any = this.db.collection(collectionName).find({_id: {$gt: 
cursor = cursor.sort({firstName: 1});
cursor = cursor.limit(limit);

return cursor.toArray();
```

Some clarifications:

1. `startId` is a valid, existing _id of an object
2. `limit` is a variable holding an positive integer value
3. sorting and limit works as expected, just the selection of the next elements is wrong, so the `{_id: {$gt: startId}};` messes up the selection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every MongoDB's Aggregation Framework operation's context is restricted to a single document. There's no mechanism like window functions in SQL. Your only way is to use `$group` to get an array which contains all your documents and then get `Austin`'s index to be able to apply [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/index.html):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $sort: { firstName: 1 }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            nextNPeople: {
                $slice: [ "$docs", { $add: [ { $indexOfArray: [ "$docs.firstName", "Austin" ] }, 1 ] }, 1 ]
            }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$nextNPeople" },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$nextNPeople"
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9cf380aXHqi)

Depending on your data size / MongoDB performance, above solution may or may not be acceptable - it's up to you to decide if you want to deploy such code on production since `$group` operation can be pretty heavy.

Comment: Hey, thanks @mickl for the quick reply. I was checking the aggregation documentation as well. Considering that my collection is a few hundred lines long, and I don't expect it to go beyond a couple thousand in the foreseeable future, I am inclined to just get the whole list from Mongo sorted and splice it in TypeScript as I need to. Nonetheless I accepted your solution because it solves the question in Mongoesque way.

Comment: Instead of `{ $slice: [ <array>, <position>, 1 ] }` you can also use `{ $arrayElemAt: [ <array>, <position> ] }` (new in version 3.2)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit that's true I can do that for one element but I think OP was looking for more generic solution, thanks!